# Printing variable length unpacked items from iterable

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

I'm trying to unpack student name and marks from a record and print them. I'm seeing only 1st item in marks instead of whole list of marks.

```
records = [
    ("Name1", 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5),
    ("Name2", 2, 3, 8, 9, 10),
    ("Name3", 8, 9, 2, 3, 1)
    ]
for name, *marks in records:
    print("Name: {0}, Marks: {1}".format(name, *marks))`
```

Output:

```
Name: Name1, Marks: 1
Name: Name2, Marks: 2
Name: Name3, Marks: 8`
```

Why other values for marks are not printed?
If I try to following, then whole list of marks is printed.

```
for name, *marks in records:
    print(name, *marks)`
```

Output:

```
Name1 1 2 3 4 5
Name2 2 3 8 9 10
Name3 8 9 2 3 1
```

Comment: Because in format you only ask for `{0}` and `{1}` to be shown... If `{1}` should be all of `marks`, *don't* use `*` to pass it as multiple separate parameters.

Comment: you can not put multiple items into a single fomat specifier `{}`

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe for pointing that out, spot on! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you only see the first item is because you did not specify a `{2}`, `{3}`, etc.

You can however use `str.join` for example to join the remaining elements together, like:

```
for name, *marks in records:
    print("Name: {0}, Marks: {1}".format(name, ' '.join(map(str, marks))))
```

which will yield:

```
Name: Name1, Marks: 1 2 3 4 5
Name: Name2, Marks: 2 3 8 9 10
Name: Name3, Marks: 8 9 2 3 1
```